# What is QuoteAssetVolume and BaseAssetVolume?

Tags: api, exchange-rate, terminology

This is a JSON result for a candle returned by an exchange API for ETHBTC:

```
{ openTime: 1517340600000,
  open: '0.10635000',
  high: '0.10742000',
  low: '0.10635000',
  close: '0.10687200',
  volume: '600.53200000',
  closeTime: 1517340899999,
  quoteAssetVolume: '27.65975320',
  trades: 1233,
  baseAssetVolume: '259.09000000' }
```

What is `quoteAssetVolume` and `baseAssetVolume`?

Comment: @Saxtheowl and Ole: I see that you readded the tag [tag:API]. I don't feel strongly about it, but figured I could explain why I had removed it in the first place. Tags on Stackexchange are used to describe the _topic_ of a question. This question asks about terminology in the context of exchange rates. The terms were found by using an API, but the question is not about APIs. :)

Comment: @Murch ah yes, sorry for rushing a little too much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`baseAssetVolume` is the quantity shown as the amount of coins received by the buyer whereas the `quoteAssetVolume` is the amount paid by the payer